# Xcode Is it possible to create a UITest project only for a given received IPA file?

Tags: ios, xcode, xctest

I would like to hire a UITester for a iOS app. I would like that he write automated tests with Xcode but I don't want to share my project with him. So my idea is to send him an app file.

I have tested my idea with Xcode but I am blocked by an error "No target application path specified via test configuration: <XCTestConfiguration: 0x6000019ec000>"

My test project has only a UITest target so that means I can't select a host app. I have the app file but I don't know how to make it selectable in Target Application on General tab of the target.

Any ideas?

Comment: Couldn't it help to create a workspace regrouping the two projects ?

Comment: @dspr If you mean by creating a workspace for the app and UITest targets then no. I don't want to share my app sources